# Copy value in rows by level Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I would like to add the value online by level. If I find a value other than 0 in row 0 for column 1 the whole row must contain the value differents, how explained in my example. I'm not sure how to get around the problem. If you have any ideas

Input :

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Level1 - Code' : [0, 0, 0, 2],
    'Level2 - Code' : [0, 1, 0, 0],
    'Level3 - Code' : [2, 0, 0, 0],
    'Level4 - Code' : [0, 0, 0, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output :

```
data = {
    'Level1 - Code' : [0, 0, 0, 2],
    'Level2 - Code' : [0, 1, 0, 2],
    'Level3 - Code' : [2, 1, 0, 2],
    'Level4 - Code' : [2, 1, 0, 2]
}

df_output = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df_output)
```

I try to do that whit this :

```
def f(x):
    lst_value = list(x.values)
    if 2 in lst_value:
        index = lst_value.index(2)
        lst_value[index:] = [2] * len(lst_value[index:])

    return pd.Series(lst_value, index = list(x.index))

df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis = 1)
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
df_output = df.cummax(axis=1)
```

output:

```
   Level1 - Code  Level2 - Code  Level3 - Code  Level4 - Code
0              0              0              2              2
1              0              1              1              1
2              0              0              0              0
3              2              2              2              2
```